# hadoop2.8 hdfs dfs -ls / no display

Tags: hadoop2

no error info, but no file/dir display as well, what's the problem?

my system is VMware ubuntu16.04

[image]

Comment: May be try to create any directory or put any file into HDFS?

Comment: I understand now. Thanks a lot!